# Why is the code "foo::foo::foo::foob" compiling?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, language-lawyer, names

A co-worker accidentally wrote code like this:

```
struct foo {
  foo() : baz(foobar) {}
  enum bar {foobar, fbar, foob};
  bar baz;
};

void f() {
  for( auto x : { foo::foobar,
                  foo::fbar,
                  foo::
                  foo::
                  foo::foob } );
    // ...
}
```

GCC 5.1.0 compiles this.

What's the rule that makes this compile?

Comment: can you be a bit more specific regarding what part you don't expect to compile cleanly?

Comment: It doesn't: https://godbolt.org/g/j2AbVn

Comment: There is a missing include file and the for loop is missing a statement but apart from that it compiles

Comment: This can be simplified to `struct foo { static const int v{42}; }; auto x{foo::foo::foo::foo::foo::v};`

Comment: @sbi Which part makes you confusing? The injected class name? The range-based for loop?

Comment: @Johan Also, this compiler uses C++98 by default. Adding e.g. ``-std=c++11`` to the compiler options fixes this.

Comment: Are you asking why `foo::foo::foo::foob` does not fail with postfixing the constructor by `::` or what is the exact expectation?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The [injected-class-name](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/classes) is used here,

> the name of the class within its own definition acts as a public member type alias of itself for the purpose of [lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup#Injected_class_name) (except when used to name a [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor)): this is known as injected-class-name

then

```
foo::
foo::
foo::foob
```

i.e. `foo::foo::foo::foob` is same as `foo::foob`.

And then `for (auto x : {foo::foobar, foo::fbar, foo::foob })` is a [range-based for loop (since C++11)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), which iterates on the [braced-init-list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) formed by the 3 enumerators.

Answer (score 4):

I changed this code to this:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
struct foo {
  foo() : baz(foobar) {}
  enum bar {foobar, fbar, foob};
  bar baz;
};

int main() {
  for( auto x : { foo::foobar,
                  foo::fbar,
                  foo::
                  foo::
                  foo::foob } )
                  {
                      std::cout << "x=" << x << std::endl;
                  }
  return 0;
}
```

for loop runs 3 times. output is: "x=1 x=2 x=3".

---

`foo::foo::foo::foob` is the same `foo::foob`.
So

```
for( auto x : { foo::foobar,
                  foo::fbar,
                  foo::
                  foo::
                  foo::foob } )
```

is the same

```
for( auto x : { foo::foobar, foo::fbar, foo::foob } )
{
}
```

It means that `x` is in range `{ foo::foobar, foo::fbar, foo::foob }`