# What happens when Injected-Class-Name occurs? (C++)

Tags: c++, class, scope, name-lookup, injected-class-name

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name

> In a class scope, the name of the current class is treated as if it
>   were a public member name; this is called injected-class-name. The
>   point of declaration of the name is immediately following the opening
>   brace of the class definition.

```
int X;
struct X {
    void f() {
        X* p; // OK. X refers to the injected-class-name
        ::X* q; // Error: name lookup finds a variable name, which hides the struct name
    }
};
```

So what is really happening in the code? Is `X* p` turned into `X::X* p`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So what is really happening in the code? Is X* p turned into `X::X*` p?

Basically.  The name lookup rules start in the narrowest scope.  When you do `X* p;` in `f` is looks in `f`'s scope and doesn't find anything.  Then it checks `X`'s scope since `f` is scoped to `X`.  It finds `X` since it is injected into the class scope so it stops there and you get the class type.

When you do `::X* q;` then `::X` says look for `X` in the global namespace, and there is finds a variable, not a type so you get an error.

Comment: So the reason why something like `X::X::foo` can occur (something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46805449/why-is-the-code-foofoofoofoob-compiling?noredirect=1&lq=1) is because Injected-Class-Name ignores those scope lookups and simply does X::foo?

Comment: @csguy It doesn't ignore it per se, it's just that `X::` contains `X` and `f` in this case.  `X` because it is injected via the compiler and `f` because you defined it.  If you do `X::X` then your right back to where you started and again have `X` and `f` as valid names.  Make sense?

Comment: Oh I see. `X` is injected because it's not stated as some member name because it's just the class name?

Comment: @csguy When you create a class, the compiler makes the class name a member of the class.  So `class_name::class_name` is always valid an since `class_name::class_name` is `class_name`, you can again access it's members and keep going like `X::X::X::X::X::X::X::X::X::X::X::X::X::f();` if you really want to.

Comment: And that's specifically because of Injected-Class-Name right?

Comment: Yes.  If the name were not injected then `class_name::class_name` would no be valid (constructors are not accessible)

Comment: Now that I understand this, referring to your answer, when you say that `X* p` essentially becomes `X::X* p`, this is because `X` is injected as a member of the class so and variable declared with `X` will refer to it right? This would be more visible in templates where the type `X<T>` for example is injected and all `X` in the template will refer to `X<T>`

Comment: @csguy Yep.  Isn't C++ fun? ;)

Answer (score 4):

This qualified name `::X` is searched in the global namespace. As there is no type with such a name (the variable declaration hides the type `struct X`) the compiler issues an error.

You could use an elaborated name like

```
int X;
struct X {
    void f() {
        X* p; // OK. X refers to the injected-class-name
        struct ::X* q; // OK. elaborated name struct ::X
    }
};
```