Namespace-class resolution for static methods and attributes in C++
I'm facing a weird behavior in namespace resolution for static methods and attributes defined in a class. It seems that the repetition of the class-namespace resolution operator :: is allowed for these cases but I would have expected a compiler failure as in case of "instance" methods and attributes.
Below is a code example tried on different compilers and platforms with Compiler Explorer (https://godbolt.org/z/cT7cfET7j)
class A {
public:
    static void foo(){};
    static int s_value;
};

namespace ns {
    void foo(){};
    static void bar(){};
}

int A::s_value{42};

int main(){
    const int x = A::A::A::s_value; // Works // triple resolution of A::!
    A::A::foo();                    // Works // double resolution of A::!
    ns::foo(); 
    //ns::ns::foo();    // compiler error: 'ns::ns' has not been declared
    return 0;
}`

Is there a C++-explanation for this?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25549652/why-is-there-an-injected-class-name & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46805449/why-is-the-code-foofoofoofoob-compiling

TL;DR every class has a hidden using A = A; type alias in it, pointing to itself. It's called the injected-class-name.
